# MultipartConfig changing path in real time

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm using MultipartConfig to define a specific url where I can store files with jetty, but how can I change this value depending of the user request?

For example write in /tmp/upload/share the user file.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @MultipartConfig(location="/tmp/upload", fileSizeThreshold=1024)
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/upload"}, name="upload")
    public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {


        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

            int i=0;
            for(Part part: req.getParts())
            {
                part.write(String.format(part.getName(),i++));
            }

        }
    }
```

With this code I change the name of the file, but I can't change the file path.

Comment: Is the goal to write the request.part to any arbitrary directory and filename?

Answer (score 2):

The use of `Part.write(String relativeFilename)` is for the management of those temporary files (once the servlet finishes its dispatch, those files are deleted).

That method exists to make sure that files in memory are written to disk.

Its up to you to move the file out from the temporary location to a more permanent location (such as another filesystem location, or database, or CMS, or CDN, or archive location, etc...)

Comment: I tested and the files are not deleted... I would like that they were send to a specific path in the file system instead immedialty

Comment: Basicaly how can I change the file in a thread way... could be also an answer to my question